# Remove key from known_hosts

Tags: ssh, hosts, openssh, man-in-the-middle

I built several virtual machines during the last few weeks. The problem is, the `.ssh/known_hosts` gives me the [Man in the middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) warning. This happens because another fingerprint is associated with the virtual machine IP.

In the `.ssh/known_hosts` file, however, I don't find the record related to the IP, only two bizarre, key-like strings and "ssh-rsa".

Does anyone have any ideas about how to remove the old key from `known_hosts`?

Comment: The "bizarre, key-like strings" you refer to are the hashed hosts/ip addresses. This a security feature which helps stops an intruder from knowing which systems you have access to. If you see this then your ssh_config has ```HashKnownHosts yes``` set.

Comment: If you feel the file contents are too confusing, you probably have line-wrapping activated. Deactivate it. All lines start with a host name or an IP address.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
sed -i '6d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Will modify the file ~/.ssh/known_hosts:6 , removing the 6th line.

In my opinion, using `ssh-keygen -R` is a better solution for an openssh power user, while your regular Linux admin would do better to keep his/her sed skills fresh by using the above method.

Comment: I don't think it's a good advice to edit a configuration file manually if you have an official application for that. Taking risks doesn't make you a pro, finding the quickest and safest option does. It's like telling people to go ahead and edit `/etc/sudoers` without `visudo`. If you want to sharpen your `sed` skills, go ahead and do that without messing up your system.

Comment: "if you have an official application for that" => both `ssh-keygen -R` and `sed -i {line}d` are pretty "official", and both will work for the foreseeable future. Util ssh-keygen allows removal by line number, both are perfectly acceptable (because, line numbers are often easier to deal with, and less error prone, than dealing with modern data center host-names).

Comment: A)The deletion of specifically the 6th line, is all very "look no hands". No explanation at all as to what is significant about the 6th line of the file?!  B)Also `man ssh-keygen` mentions `ssh-keygen -R hostname`  you've just said `ssh-keygen -R` with no hostname specified, and you haven't explained what you mean by that.

Comment: When we aren't using default SSH port, then the hostname for `-R` should be provided with the following format `'[<host-name OR IP>]:<SSH Port>'`. For example: `ssh-keygen -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts -R '[192.168.23.2]:1234'`

Comment: As a rule I agree with other comments that `ssh-keygen -R` should be used whenever possible. I had issues with that as using the hotsname would delete the new key instead of the old now-offending one... eventually I figured out that I could provide the IP address IP address printed in the ssh error message instead of the hostname, but the sed was next as nothing else was working. Last resort!

Answer (score 280):

There is an ssh-keygen switch (`-R`) for this.

`man ssh-keygen` reads:

> ### `-R` *hostname*
>
> Removes all keys belonging to `hostname` from a `known_hosts` file.  This
>                option is useful to delete hashed hosts (see the `-H` option above).

Comment: This is the easiest and safest method.

Comment: Note: This will change the permissions of the known_hosts file to 0600. If you have a shared known_hosts file for any reason, this could disable the sharing of it.

Comment: and the correct one.  Also, I had to do `[localhost]:port`, using the brackets because I used a custom port I guess =/.  Like others have said, I would also use the no SSH key-checking approach for my transient/test system development.

Comment: This removes all ocurences so the best way. You can add new key with: `ssh-keyscan -H my.ssh.server.example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts;`

Comment: adding an example would add great value to this post

Comment: For some strange reason, the hostname is written in lowercase in my `known_hosts`, although the real hostname is UPPER-CASE.
I'm running an expect script, and unfortunately, the bash upper to lowercase variable expansion ( `${hostname,,}` ) is not working.  I've tried to find an -ignore-case or equivalent in `ssh-keygen`: no luck.

Comment: @Pysis Thanks! your suggestion worked for me!

Answer (score 228):

The simplest solution is:

```
rm -f .ssh/known_hosts
```

ssh will recreate the file again, but you lose key checking for other hosts!

Or, you can use:

```
ssh-keygen -R "hostname"
```

Or the ssh "man-in-the-middle" message should indicate which line of the known_hosts file has the offending fingerprint.  Edit the file, jump to that line and delete it.

Comment: Correct - the line number is somewhat shy : "Add correct host key in /home/adam/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /home/udi/.ssh/known_hosts:48". Removed line 48 and it worked!

Comment: `ssh-keygen -R hostname` will work too.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `ssh-keygen -R`. I just wanted to remove a host from `known_hosts` for testing purposes (i.e. without that the host key changed) and this hosts entry was hashed...

Comment: If we remove that file, other keys will remove too.

Comment: Removing the file is a bad advice, it's like telling someone to buy a new PC because the old one has a broken mouse. Manually editing a file that can be edited by an official application is also a bad idea. The `ssh-keygen` option was added because of a comment, but with no explanation. I don't think this answer deserves so many upvotes.

Comment: -1 because of the whole "delete the whole known_hosts file" first lines. This is a terrible, terrible, terrible thing to propose, and should be edited out.

Comment: This solution is overkill. Just remove the offending line. That's it.

Comment: Are newest known_hosts added on the top line or bottom?

Comment: This answer could be improved by placing the good advice at the top, and then presenting the other option as an "if all else fails" option.

Answer (score 48):

You need to run the following command to get rid of this problem. Open the terminal and type the following command:

For all examples below just replace the value after `-R`:

```
ssh-keygen -R server-name
ssh-keygen -R server.ip.addre.ss
ssh-keygen -R 202.54.1.5
ssh-keygen -R server1.example.com
```

Comment: This method has already been suggested in the previous answers. Could you expanded upon what is different in your answer?

Comment: @Burgi - this answer gives more detail about the syntax of `ssh-keygen -R` than any of the other answers so far. It show by example exactly what you can write after `-R`. So this answer is worthwhile, even though it is not a totally new answer.

Comment: @Yitz My comment was made as part of review. At the time (18 months ago) I thought the question needed a little help to make it even better.

Comment: Seems it doesn't work if some of the hosts are on the different port than 22.

Answer (score 31):

All answers are good, but for real SSH pro we have missing information how to remove ssh signature with (non-standard) port number.

- Simple SSH host signature remove command:

  ```
    ssh-keygen -R example.com
  ```
- Complex ssh key remove, e.g. you connect to ssh on non standard port 222:

  ```
    ssh example.com -p 222
  ```

and you get warning, and to remove this, you need to use **square brackets** colon port number:

```
    ssh-keygen -R [example.com]:222
```

Note, that probably there will be IP record for the same host, so you will need to remove that one also.

Hope this helps for non-standard configuration users.

Answer (score 20):

The warning will tell you the exact line in the known hosts file.

Here's an example:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The RSA host key for foo-bar.net has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address 127.0.0.1
is unchanged. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
Offending key for IP in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
```

See the `/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6` part? It specifies the file and line number.

Answer (score 10):

You can also instruct ssh to not check the known_hosts file using the UserKnownHostsFile and StrictHostKeyChecking flags.

For instance:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@example.com
```

For ease of use you can alias this:

```
alias boldssh='ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Now you can just boldssh whenever you are sure you trust the server's certificate.

Comment: What a horrible idea. Permanently disable a layer of security just because you're too lazy keeping your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` up-to-date? Why not just go ahead and use `telnet`? "whenever you are sure" - if you are ever sure, then you have no idea what a MITM attack is and you should probably spend some time reading some good literature.

Comment: Based on the OP's question I think this is a valid answer.  Sometimes you have a test system that you're creating/destroying a lot of VMs on.  (I'm doing this right now as I prep for the RHCE exam.)  There might not be any security implications.  While noting the security implications is great, I don't think this has to be labeled a "horrible idea".

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/a/1126243/73961

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using Ex editor:

```
ex +6d -scwq ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

where 6th is your line number mentioned in the warning message. Such as this one:

> Offending key for IP in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6 <== LINE NUMBER

---

In general, [it's advised to use `ex`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021#Using_nonstandard_tools) to [edit the files non-interactively](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/788/467), instead of `sed`, which is more a **S**tream **ED**itor and its `-i` parameter which is a non-standard FreeBSD extension.

Comment: This might be the breakthrough I need to use vim as a true Unix filter, I've been tearing my hair out trying to get it working.  Note to self:`vim -e` = `ex`

Answer (score 0):

The entry for the host name or ip should be in the first column.  The warning should also list a line number where the offending key lies.

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove a single line from known hosts with e.g. [rmknownhost](http://grosser.it/2010/06/22/remove-a-line-from-known-hosts-with-single-command) 111 (111 is the line to remove):

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
line = ARGV[0] || raise("gimme line to remove")
hosts = File.expand_path("~/.ssh/known_hosts")
content = File.readlines(hosts)
removed = content.delete_at line.to_i - 1
puts "Removed:\n#{removed}"
File.open(hosts, 'w'){|f| f.write content * ""}
```

Save this as `rmknownhost` in a folder from your `PATH`.

Comment: What's the benefit of this over doing it in any given text editor?  Is there some reason not to do it that way, like how sudoers has to be edited with visudo?

Comment: What distros come with this? Ubuntu doesn't seem to have it.

Comment: The benefit is that it's automated and quick / it's a separate binary you add yourself

Comment: You could have just posted your script here instead of linking your own blog entry that you created on the day you posted this answer. This qualifies as spam IMHO. Not to mention that you could create a simple alias to achieve the same result, no need for a 7 lines long ruby script.

Comment: or just add this to your ~/.bashrc: `sshdel() { sed -i "${@}d" ~/.ssh/known_hosts; }` and call it with `sshdel [line number]`. no ruby, no binary, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

It is a text file.  You can easily edit with vi(m) and simply delete the line in question (dd), and save the file (wq). But if there is a specific command to remove a host, that's probably the safest method.

Comment: I don't see how editing the file directly in VIM is "unsafe".  It's based on your comfort level with VIM.  Especially with this file, the biggest risk you have is deleting too many keys, in which case you'll just get prompted again.

Comment: The "safety" I was referring to involves 1) forgetting/not knowing to remove dependent info in other files (if any) and 2) Accidentally deleting more or less than needs to be, thus breaking the file.